# Cannot open OneNote file

Tags: windows-7, laptop, microsoft-office-2007, microsoft-onenote

I cannot open my .one OneNote files.

I get this **error** when I try to open my .one file in OneNote Enterprise 2007:
*This file is from a different version of OneNote. Your version cannot load this file. There may be a converter available on the Office.com Web site that will enable it to do so.*

Could it be that I had a different service pack or a different OneNote version before?
For other .one files it says that they are corrupted.

My OneNote version:
Microsoft Office OneNnote 2007 (12.0.6606.1000) SP2 MSO (12.0.6545.5004)
I am running Windows 7 x64.

I have tried several applications and methods, including:

- Office Enterprise 2007 SP2

  Office Professional Plus 2007 SP2

  EverNote

  KeyNote

  OneNoteRepair

  dragging the .one files to Microsoft Notepad but all I see is garbled text for the most part, which isn't really useful to me.

  print them to PDF. I can't even open the .one files I have. I don't have any .backup files neither.

  /forcerepair option in OneNote

None of them worked.

How do I extract the contents of the .one OneNote files I have to something readable?
I need the (important) content that is in those files.

Comment: "Could it be that I had a different service pack or a different OneNote version before?" - Did you install the previous version yourself? Maybe you had OneNote 2010 installed? Or maybe as you suspect the files are just corrupted.

Comment: Yes, I installed the previous version myself. No, I never had OneNote 2010 installed. Perhaps they are just corrupted yes. When I used GetDataBack, I noticed that the files were in completely wrong paths (e.g. c:\mydrivers\realtek).

Comment: I just tried Recuva, an recovery app. It is showing status 'Unrecoverable' next to the problematic .one files. That's not good. It's also mentioning that a couple hundred clusters of that file were overridden by my pagefile.sys

Comment: Did you try to open your OneNote file in OneNote 2010? I saw a similar message when I tried to open a OneNote created by 2010 version in 2007. If it opens fine, you can convert the file to the previous version, 2007.

Comment: Yeah but the problem is much much worse. Part of the header of those OneNote files is completely corrupted because several hexadecimal Bytes have been overridden. There is no application that I know that can fix this type of serious corruption.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you sign up for Microsoft SkyDrive - https://skydrive.live.com/ (if you have a Microsoft Live ID, you should already have an account).

Once you have uploaded the file to SkyDrive, you can try clicking on it and it should open in the web-based OneNote app.

This probably won't help if indeed the file is corrupted. But it will allow you to find out whether it was created in OneNote 2010 because, if so, it should open fine in the web application.

Comment: Well, I tried that before and it didn't help. It simply opens up a save file dialog. No OneNote online app.

Comment: Assuming you have tried with a known good OneNote file and successfully got it open in the Web App, then it seems you do have a corrupt file.